# Configuring Notepad++ for code folding

Tags: configuration, notepad++, folding

I have a file which conforms to the following standard:

```
# comment
<section> # comment
    {variant1,variant2,...}
        a="bar"
        b="b\\a\"r"
        [array]
        [+]
            elem="foo"
        [+]
            elem="bar"
        [/]
        c=."42"
        d=."xDebb1eD0e5Da11a5"
        e=."%101010"
        f=@"xaa bb cc dd"
    {/}
</>
```

I have defined a new 'language' in Notepad++ and got all my syntax highlighting working well:

```
Comment Line Style -> Open: # (red)

Operator Style -> Operators 1: = (yellow)

Operator Style -> Delimiter 1 -> Open  : <  (yellow)
                              -> Close : >
                  Delimiter 2 -> Open  : [+ (blue)
                              -> Close : ]
                  Delimiter 3 -> Open  : {  (orange)
                              -> Close : }
                  Delimiter 4 -> Open  : "  (cyan)
                              -> Escape: \
                              -> Close : "
                  Delimiter 5 -> Open  : ." (lime)
                              -> Close : "
                  Delimiter 6 -> Open  : @" (green)
                              -> Close : "
                  Delimiter 7 -> Open  : [  (purple)
                              -> Close : ]
```

...But after much searching and reading I cannot work out how to get Notepad++/Scintilla to fold the the [array], {variant} and <section> chunks of the file (which runs to several thousand lines).

I notice that if I highlight a file as HTML, then any tag (html, body, foo, wibble, etc) all fold as expected - which I will need here as the <section>, {variant} and [array] names are arbitrary.

I have worked out that if a character is defined as a delimiter, the fold'er will refuse to fold on any string which starts-with that character.

My question: With regard to this file format, how do I get Notepad++ to fold according to these rules:

```
Rule 1 -> Starts with: <*>
          Ends   with: </>
Rule 2 -> Starts with: {*}
          Ends   with: {/}
Rule 3 -> Starts with: [*] but not [+]
          Ends   with: [/]
```